# Change type of enclosure brackets with special conditions

Tags: regex, notepad++

What I'm trying to achieve is changing square brackets [] to curly/brace brackets {}.

There are two conditions, some start with [", the others end with "]

There will not be any occurrences where both exist in same string. Haven't run across any yet.

BEFORE:

```
[Strained breathing]


["Wanna Give My Love"
by The Sons of Rainier]


[Mavrick blows a fart]


["Hallelujah"
by The Sons of Rainer]


[Victor over the phone]


[The Korgi's "Everybody's
Got To Learn Sometime"]


[Lola chuckles]


["It's Good"
by Jack Hammer]


[Uno Hype's "Leave"]
```

Here's what I would like as the end results

AFTER:

```
[Strained breathing]


{"Wanna Give My Love"
by The Sons of Rainier playing}


[Mavrick blows a fart]


{"Hallelujah"
by The Sons of Rainer}


[Victor over the phone]


{The Korgi's "Everybody's
Got To Learn Sometime"}


[Lola chuckles]


{"It's Good"
by Jack Hammer}


{Uno Hype's "Leave"}
```

Here are my attempts:

```
Find:   (?=\[")([\S\s]+?)\]
Replace: \{$1\}

Find:   (?=\[[A-Z])([\S\s]+?)\"]
Replace: \{$1\}

Find:   \["([A-Z][\S\s]+?)\]
Replace: \{$1\}
```

So frustrated that my light blub is still so dim in regards to regex.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
\[("[^]]+|[^]]+")\]
```

which matches a `[` followed by either

- a `"` and some number of non-`]` characters; or
- some number of non-`]` characters followed by a `"`

and then followed by a `]`, and replace it with `{\1}`.

[Regex demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/B9c6Qt/1)

Comment: Brilliant, totally awesome. Greatly appreciated. Works like a charm. My light bulb just went up10 watts

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\[([^]["]*"[^][]*)]
```

**Explanation**

- `\[` Match `[`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^]["]*` Optionally match any char except `]` `[` `"`
  - `"` Then match a single `"`
  - `[^][]*` Optionally match any char except `]` `[`
- `)` Close group 1
- `]` Match `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y3Vnjq/1)

In the replacement use `{\1}`

[image]